# Binding the checked attribute of html input to boolean method return value in blazor

Tags: c#, html, forms, blazor

I am working on a blazor project currenty. In this project I need to add some default values to a list in my C# code. The problem is that I can not find a way to bind a boolean method return value to the "checked" attribute of an input.

**Code:**

I do have a list and I am adding an input (checkbox) field per entry in this list to my html:

```
@foreach (ProfessionViewModel prof in Professions)
{
    <div class="form-group m-1">
        <div class="form-check">

            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="@prof.Id" 
                  @onchange="eventArgs => { ToggleProfessions(prof, eventArgs.Value); }" />
                                        
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

I cant find a way to bind the "checked" attribute to a method that checks if this item exists in an other list (SelectedProfessions list, defined in @code section).

My list:

```
public List<ProfessionViewModel> SelectedProfessions { get; set; } = new List<ProfessionViewModel>();
```

My boolean return method:

```
private bool CheckIfProfessionIsAssigned(ProfessionViewModel prof)
{
    if (SelectedProfessions.Contains(prof))
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

**Problem description:**

The collection "Professions" contains all professions available in the app. In this form the user should be able to select certain professions individualy (for a profession filter).
Every selected profession is contained in the collection "SelectedProfessions". The problem is that I can't bind (or render) the checkboxes value according to the helper property "CheckIfProfessionIsAssigned", which determines if this profession is currently selected by the user.

Comment: I would use a view model that includes A Boolean checked property on each profession, then just bind that property to the input. Getting the list is just a linq query where profession checked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Didn't try these myself, but based on this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/60343185 - something like this might work to initially check the checkboxes:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="@CheckIfProfessionIsAssigned(prof)">
```

You could alternatively try to create a dictionary of integers and booleans named `professionsSelected` in which to store for each profession ID if it is selected or not, and then bind that to the checkboxes, like:

```
<input type="checkbox" @bind="@professionsSelected[prof.Id]" />
```

Comment: First suggestion worked for me after adding a "StateHasChanged". I have tried it like this in the beginning but it was the "StateHasChanged" that was missing because it was not updating automatically. Thank You!